# Query on 'object' class & 'type' class in python

Tags: python, oop

I have a query in class based OOP paradigm aspect of imperative/dynamic python language. Below is the diagram for a class hierarchy in python taken from [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fRfXenpU6M&list=PL29B31797A997C41E&index=2).

[image: class hierarchy]

As per the diagram, I understand that, Every datatype in python is a class. `bool` class is direct child of `object` class. When we create a new user-defined class(`Natalie`) then   `object` class will be an ultimate ancestor for this class. class objects(`int`/`str`/`object`) themselves are instances of `type` class. In java world we call it as 'Class' class instead of `type` class.

My question is:

1)
Is my understanding correct?

2)
If yes, Am confused with the arrow direction from  `type` to `object` class. How do i understand this?

3)
I could not understand/visualise these two phrases(in brown),  Please help me on this.

```
the object class is an instance of the type class and itself
the type class is an instance of the object class and itself
```

Comment: There are a number of problems with that diagram...

Comment: You can easily check all of this by looking at the [CPython source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/34ace7eb67e9).

Comment: @arshajii: I think "easily" is a bit of an overstatement.

Comment: @BrenBarn Maybe. In any case, I think looking at the source is very helpful when it comes to questions like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your understanding is basically right.  `type` and `object` are special in that they are the base of the type hierarchy.  Everything is an instance of `object`.  Every type/class is an instance of `type`.  So `type` is an instance of `object` and `object` is also an instance of `type`.

This means that the inheritance relationship cannot really be represented as a tree, because there is a cycle: `type` and `object` are instances of each other.  This kind of mutual inheritance is not normally possible, but that's the way it is for these fundamental types in Python: they break the rules.  The diagram is somewhat misleading since it shows `type` as inheriting from `object` but not vice versa.  Really, the arrow between `type` and `object` should be double-headed, indicating the inheritance goes both ways.

It's important to distinguish between what types/classes *inherit* from and what they are *instances* of, although this isn't directly represented in that diagram.  A class or type (like `int` or `Natalie`) is a *subclass* of `object`, but it is an *instance* of `type`.  The two statements that you refer to in Question 3 relate to this.  The `object` type is an instance of `object`, because everything is an object; `object` is also an instance of `type`, because `object` is a type (aka a class).  Likewise, `type` is an instance of `object`, because everything is an object; and `type` is also an instance of `type`, because `type` is a type (it is the type of types, and the type of user-defined classes).

There is also an inaccuracy in the diagram: `bool` is not actually a direct subclass of `object`, rather it is a subclass of `int` (which is a direct subclass of `object`).

Comment: brenban inheritance goes both ways, how do i understand this?

Comment: @Sham: I don't understand what you're asking.  What do you mean "how do you understand it"?

Comment: brenban inheritance is genrally top down from what i saw in java, so how can it be two ways?

Comment: @Sham: That's what I'm saying.  This particular inheritance relation (between `type` and `object`) in Python is special and breaks the normal rules.

Comment: brenban can you also clarify the meaning of two statements in Q3 of my query? What does instance of itself mean?

Comment: @Sham: I added a bit to my answer.

Comment: Hi Bran, One doubt from your answer- "type is an instance of object" : We have instances for classes, do you mean `object` is a class? and `type` is getting instantiated from it. This I couldn't able to understand.

Comment: @METALHEAD: Types and classes are basically the same thing.  "instance of" means the same thing for types as it does for classes.  Being an instance of a type is the same as being an instance of a class.  Beyond that I'm not sure what it is you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
print (isinstance(type,object))
print (type.__class__)
print (isinstance(object,type))
```

I dont know if that will help you more than the object but there is some empirical proof

Comment: This was a good suggestion. Could you clarify? I got type for <class 'type'> for both print(type.__class__) and print(object.__class__). Why isn't print(type.__class__)  == <class 'object'>? I thought that if the relationship between type and object is two-way, we would get that answer. What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score -1):

In Java **Object class is the super class of every class** and single inheritance is applicable, but in python it is not true.

In Java

[image]

in Python3, before inheriting from object

[image]

After inheriting object

[image]

So when you are creating a class in pythyon it is not inheriting from object. It is basically follows modular architecture. Not like java's Tree structure.