# Subclassing type vs object in Python3

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass

I've been reading about metaclasses and I got lost when it came to `type` and `object` classes.

I understand that they are at the top of the hierarchy and they are implemented in C code. 
I also understand that `type` inherits from `object` and that `object` is an instance of `type`.

In one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22921202/2808371) I've found on SO, someone said - in reagards to `object-type` relationship - that:

> This kind of mutual inheritance is not normally possible, but that's the way it is for these fundamental types in Python: they break the rules.

My question is why is it implemented this way, what is purpose of such implementation? What problems does it solve/what are the benefits of this design? Couldn't it be just `type` or just `object` class that is at the top of the hierarchy that every class inherits from?

Finally, is there any difference between subclassing from `object` vs subclassing from `type`, and when would I want to use one over the other?

```
class Foo(object):
    pass
```

vs

```
class Foo(type):
    pass
```

Comment: That answer is pretty misleading. There's no mutual inheritance going on; the answer doesn't do a good job of communicating the difference between instance and subclass relations.

Comment: `type` is the base metaclass in Python. (Every class is an object, and a class's class is its metaclass.) You shouldn't subclass `type` unless you are intentionally trying to create a metaclass.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no cross-inheritance between `object` and `type`. In fact, cross-inheritance is impossible.

```
# A type is an object
isinstance(int, object) # True

# But an object is not necessarily a type
isinstance(object(), type) # False
```

What is true in Python is that...

### Everything *is* an object

Absolutly everything, `object` is the only base type.

```
isinstance(1, object) # True
isinstance('Hello World', object) # True
isinstance(int, object) # True
isinstance(object, object) # True
isinstance(type, object) # True
```

### Everything *has* a type

Everything has a type, either built-in or user-defined, and this type can be obtained with `type`.

```
type(1) # int
type('Hello World') # str
type(object) # type
```

### Not everything is a type

That one is fairly obvious

```
isinstance(1, type) # False
isinstance(isinstance, type) # False
isinstance(int, type) # True
```

### `type` is its own type

This is the behaviour which is specific to `type` and that is not reproducible for any other class.

```
type(type) # type
```

In other word, `type` is the only object `X` in Python such that `type(X) is X`

```
type(type) is type # True

# While...
type(object) is object # False
```

This is because `type` is the only built-in metaclass. A metaclass is simply a class, but its instances are also classes themselves. So in your example...

```
# This defines a class
class Foo(object):
    pass

# Its instances are not types
isinstance(Foo(), type) # False

# While this defines a metaclass
class Bar(type):
    pass

# Its instances are types
MyClass = Bar('MyClass', (), {})

isinstance(MyClass, type) # True

# And it is a class
x = MyClass()

isinstance(x, MyClass) # True
```

Comment: Note: Some of the "always" claims here only apply to Python 3; in Python 2, old-style classes had a completely separate type hierarchy (and `type(x)` where `x` was an instance of an old-style class always told you, fairly uselessly, that the instance was of type `instance`, not the class it was an instance of).

Comment: All the above is true, I carefully worded it so it is in both Python2 and 3. The catch would have been to say that `type(Foo()) is Foo` is always true. Your example correctly shows that it isn't even though `isinstance(Foo(), Foo)` is true. The rest is still true, everything is an object, everything has a type and `type` is the only object which is its own type. But please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Ah, yes. On rechecking, even instances of old-style classes claim to be instances of `object`, despite inheriting from `object` being the way you make a class new-style. Somehow, `isinstance(Foo(), object)` is true, even as `issubclass(Foo, object)` is false, because `instance` itself is a subclass of `object`. The hackery in the Py2 type system is faintly magical at times. :-)

Comment: I might also add under "Everything _is_ an object", this: `isinstance(type, object) # True`

Answer (score 3):

In Python everything is an object. Also every object has a type. In fact the type of an object is also an object and therefore must also have its own type. Types have a special type that is called `type`. This (like any other type) is an object and is therefore an instance of `object`.

*Every* object is an instance of `object` including any *type* of any object. So `int` is an object and so is `str` as well as more obvious examples such as `1` and `'asd'`. Anything that you can refer to or assign to a variable in Python is an instance of `object`.

Since `object` is a type it is an instance of `type`. This means that `object` and `type` are both instances of each other. This is not "inheritance" regardless of what the other answer you linked says. The relationship is the same as the relationship between `int` and `1`: the object resulting from `1` is an instance of `int`. The quirk here is that `object` and `type` are both instances of each other.

From a Python perspective these two mean different things. The `object` type has an ontological role: everything is an object (and nothing else exists). So to say that `type` is an object just means that it *exists* as far as Python's model is concerned. On the other hand `object` is the base type of all objects so it is a type. As a type it must be an instance of `type` which like any other object is an instance of `object`.

As far as the interpreters are implemented: the fact that `type` is an instance of `object` is convenient since it maintains "everything is an object" which is useful for e.g. deallocating objects at shutdown. The fact that `object` is an instance of `type` is useful since it makes it straight-forward to ensure that it behaves like other type objects.

Comment: This is good info, is there a more general, official body of knowledge about this?