# what is the difference between object and type in python

Tags: python, object, new-style-class

We have two types of classes in Python 2.x as all know like Old style classes and new Style classes

```
class OldStyle:
    pass
```

The `type` of instances of Oldstyle classes is always `instance`

```
class NewStyle(object):
    pass
```

New style classes have an advantage of `method descriptors`, `super`, `getattribute` etc.,
The `type` of instances of NewStyle classes is the class name itself

when you check type of NewStyle class is type and type of `object` is also type

```
In [5]: type(NewStyle)
Out[5]: type

In [6]: type(object)
Out[6]: type

In [7]: type(type)
Out[7]: type
```

So what is the concept of inheriting new style classes from `object`, as we have seen above that `type(type)` is also `type` and `type(object)` is also `type`

Why can't we inherit new style classes directly from `type`?

Can we assume below points to differentiate between `object` and `type`?

1. If we inherit/create a class from `type` as below, we will certainly end up in creating a metaclass? (Everything is an object in python, including classes, are objects of some other class which is `type`)

`class NewStyle(type):
      pass`

When Python interpreter sees the above code, it would create an object/instance of type `class`(class object) with a name NewStyle(which is not a normal instance but class object)

2. If we inherit/create a class from `object`, it will create a normal instance/object of the class

`class NewStyle(object):
       pass
isinstance(NewStyle, type)`

`obj = NewStyle()
 print isinstance(obj, NewStyle) # True
 print isinstance(NewStyle, type) #True
 print isinstance(NewStyle, object) #True
 print isinstance(object, type) # True
 print isinstance(type, object) # True`

So finally we use `type` to create classes, but we use `object` to create instances?

Comment: I believe I once wrote an answer that might help you here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49143578/5079316